# Trocar valores de objetos vindo da api?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

é possivel mudar valores no frontend vindo a api?

Por exemplo, eu tenho uma api que me retorna isso:

```
"data":[
"nome": "sp",
"nome": "mg",
"nome": "rj"
]
```

Aí eu por exemplo faço um simples request dela usando `GET`

```
this.axios.get("http://localhost/api/exemplo/").then(response => {
    this.items = response.data;
});
```

Tem como no frontend eu trocar esses valores para eles serem exibidos de uma forma mais "agradável" pro usuário? Isso sem ter que alterar nada no banco, e exibindo isso num v-for.

Como por exemplo : São Paulo, Minas Gerais, Rio de Janeiro

Comment: Como assim **trocar esses valores para eles serem exibidos de uma forma mais "agradável" pro usuário** e **exibindo isso num v-for.**??

Comment: Se eu fizesse um v-for com essa array `items` ele me exibiria: `sp`, `mg`, `rj`.
E eu queria saber se há alguma forma de mudar isso. Esse é só um exemplo de algo próximo do que eu quero fazer, que realmente não rola trocar os nomes pelo banco.

Comment: Ué claro que tem como, partindo do seu exemplo que os valores são um **array**, você pode pegar e mostrar cada valor separadamente através do `índice` do array, não precisa fazer um **for**.

Comment: O retorno da API que você mostrou não é nem JSON válido. É um array? é um objeto? se for array vai dar erro porque um array literal não tem chaves, e se for um objeto também vai dar erro porque não dá pra ter chaves duplicadas.

Ajusta isso pra gente entender melhor por favor

Answer (score 1):

Recomendo se for possível, você aplicar essa alteração na sua api, pois normalmente seu front-end deve ser apenas um consultor de dados, caso você tenha essa informação no lado da api, pode tentar enviar esses dados da seguinte maneira:

```
"data": [
   {"acornym": "sp", full_name: "São Paulo"},
   {"acornym": "mg", full_name: "Minas Gerais"}
]
```

Mas como fazer isso se você não pode alterar no banco? Bom, se estivermos falando apenas de estados brasileiros, recomendo vc usar alguma solução de internacionalização, e usar as siglas como chaves e as strings como valor, essa solução se limita a opções fixas no seu sistema, pois não necessita de alterações no banco de dados. Abaixo deixarei um exemplo de arquivo `.yml` para deixar mais claro o que eu quis dizer

```
sp: 'São Paulo'
mg: 'Minas Gerais'
...
```

Caso as opções sejam dinâmicas, e você não tenha controle, recomendo fazer um esforço e criar mais uma informação no seu banco de dados. Espero ter ajudado, abraços!

Comment: Mas não é errado eu ter 2 colunas no banco pra esse tipo de coisa?

Comment: Não, vamos imaginar uma tabela chamada Estado, poderíamos ter dois atributos: acronym, e full_name, o que nos ajuda a guardar a informação por completo.

Comment: Então são duas colunas, em todo caso. Mas valeu.

Answer (score 1):

Uma forma que utilizo para alterar um retorno é pela função `map()`. Usando o seu exemplo ficaria assim:

```
this.axios.get("http://localhost/api/exemplo/").then(response => {
   this.items = response.data.map(item => {
      //alteracões que desejar no objeto item
      return item;
   });
});
```

Você pode usar a mesma ideia para filtrar:

```
this.axios.get("http://localhost/api/exemplo/").then(response => {
   this.items = response.data.filter(item => {
      //Se o retorno for true então fará parte do novo array.
      return item.nome == "sp";
   });
});
```